# How can I parse date and time directly with timezone

Tags: date, go, time, timezone

I have these codes:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tzJakarta, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Jakarta")
    stringTime := fmt.Sprintf("05-05-2019 05:11 %s", tzJakarta) 
    parsedTime, _ := time.Parse("02-01-2006 15:04 MST", stringTime)

    fmt.Println(tzJakarta)
    fmt.Println(stringTime)
    fmt.Println(parsedTime)
}
```

The output is:

```
Asia/Jakarta
05-05-2019 05:11 Asia/Jakarta
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

What I expect is this:

```
Asia/Jakarta
05-05-2019 05:11 Asia/Jakarta
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0700 UTC
```

How can I achieve this? Is this possible at all with Go?

Comment: **Don't discard errors**, especially from code that's not working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never have `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0700 UTC` because you're ignoring errors, `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` is a zero value. Last statement returns an error about parsing, here is a right version.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Jakarta")

    // Note: without explicit zone, returns time in given location.
    const shortForm = "02-01-2006 15:04"
    t, _ := time.ParseInLocation(shortForm, "05-05-2019 05:11", loc)
    fmt.Println(t)

}
```

Output:

```
2019-05-05 05:11:00 +0700 WIB
```

(WIB – Western Indonesian Time)

[Platground](https://play.golang.org/p/_3IDH97IbRp)